# How can I hide the rows of my Matrix when full of 0s?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to learn how to use Power BI and there is something I want to do but don't know how.

I have a Balance Sheet in a Matrix covering 3 years, from 2020 to 2022.

It is a big document so there are a lot of lines. But many of them only have zeros. Which is a waste of space for me. Here's a picture to show you how it looks:

[image]

**How can I hide those lines without deleting them?**

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Just check put your measure into filter pane If you can't see them there, then just apply filter (is not 0). see the picture:

[image: FGH]

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer.
The only problem with your suggestion is that, if for example I have no data for 2022 but data for 2021 and I use your filter idea, yes, the 2022 row with no data will disapear but also the data for 2021 that is on the same row :/.

I don't know if you understand my point

Comment: Yes, I understand your point. Then try to add a condition to your measure like this: if ([measure] <>0, [measure]) then test it again.